# MSBuild (uBuild) is incorrectly identifying a previously built DLL, and rebuilding

Tags: c#, dll, groovy, msbuild

We have a solution that contains 9 DLLs, but I have simplified this example down to just 3 Library projects.

Project 1 has no dependencies and builds correctly each time. We build from scratch, then it gets copied to a shared repo.

Project 2 has one dependency on Project 1. We have scripts (Groovy) in place that pull the previous compiled DLL (Project 1) down and compiles Project 2 using the previously built Project 1 as expected. (No recompile of Project 1)

If a build happens here, both projects get identified as:

> Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date
>   with respect to the input files.

Project 3 has a dependency on Project 2. The scripts in place (Groovy) pull down the pre-compiled Project 1 and Project 2.

When MSBuild does its check to determine if either of Project 1 or Project 2 has changed and needs to be rebuilt, Project 1's DLL gets used without another compile, but Project 2 gets rebuilt every time stating this in the build log.

> Input file "D:\targetFolder\bin\Project1.dll" is newer than output
>   file "obj\Release\Project2.dll"

, and proceeds to rebuild Project 2 every time.

Unsure why it comparing the Project 1 DLL against the Project 2 DLL. I assume it is checking the Timestamp.

Using csc.exe...

Stumped in Charlotte.

Comment: MSBuild will consider a target (CoreCompile) up-to-date if its output file is the same age or older than its input file or files. Have you run MS Build with diagnostic logger to see what inputs are being used to the build targets? Are you actually building a sln (solution) file or a hand crafted build project?

Are you using Project References or file\assembly references for the relationship between Project 1 and project 2?

Comment: In your case Project2 contains a reference to Project1, which means that Project1.dll is one of the input to produce Project2.dll. This explains why msbuild compares Project1.dll and Project2.dll timestamps. You should check the log -- and your custom build actions along the way -- to see if there is any task that touches Project1.dll after it has been copied to the final destination.